# Is it possible to count no of human faces in web cam `capture` from server side?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-4.0, image-capture

i am new to ASP.Net 
      I want to implement project which is need to every `random` time web cam captures images from the `client side`. 
      And I want to send those capture images to Server, There i want to `count` no of human faces found in that images and return messages to clients.

Here I am using `Silver light plug` in for captures images .....

Please if any suggestions or  any ideas please let me know..
and if any `English` mistakes please edit the question

Comment: I do not have much idea about this but this link might help you :- http://kodefun.junian.net/2011/07/camera-face-detection-in-c-using-emgu.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number of faces from the images. Do the following steps

1- Capture the image

2- Send it to the server via Stream or some other method

3- Follow this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/462527/Camera-Face-Detection-in-Csharp-Using-Emgu-CV-Open

The tutorial uses Emgu CV library. It is for .net and it works.

Comment: It works only in winforms. But when I am tries to convert it into Asp.net it gives exception

Comment: @Behrox I have followed link as u mentioned in answer it works in winforms but where as in asp.net it throwns exception

Comment: i have tried with different openCV libraries it gives unable to load `cvExtern.dll`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028523/unable-to-load-cvextern-in-a-c-sharp-project

Comment: I have seen that Question @Behroz. thanks for responding it works fine.