# cvinvoke dllnotfoundexception using emgucv on ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu-14.04, monodevelop, emgucv

I have this program and at some point, it takes the square root of an image. The program calls CvInvoke.cvSqrt(A.Img.Ptr, Dest.Ptr); where a.img and dest are both cv images.

When the program gets to this line, it throws a dllnotfound exception saying it cant find cvextern. I know that cvextern points to most other cv dlls and so I think that its because of cvinvoke that I am having this problem. The rest of the emgucv stuff works so far, its only cvinvoke that doesnt seem to exist.

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and emgucv version 2.4.9 and monodevelop 3.12

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028523/unable-to-load-cvextern-in-a-c-sharp-project

Comment: @RobertN So as clarification, I should get those opencv dll files and add them as references to my project? Sorry about the simple questions, I haven't worked with something this complicated before.