# Emgu 3.4.3 error "unable to load DLL cvextern"

Tags: c#, emgucv

Although this problem has been around for some time, I couldn't yet find a solution that worked in my case. Here's the problem again: When using EmguCV I always get the "unable to load DLL 'cvextern'" error. In my case when I try to capture an image from an external webcam via "VideoCapture"

Here's my Setup:

- SharpDevelop 5.1.0 as C# IDE ( I just like it that's why I still use it )
- EmguCV 3.4.3.3016
- Win7 64-bit

What I tried yet:

- I placed all the EmguCV DLLs in the Debug folder of my project
- I added 2 folders x64 and x86 also in Debug containing the OpenCV DLLs (concrt140, cvextern, msvcp140, opencv_ffmpeg343 and vcruntime140) so my IDE can choose which ones to take ( tried both version's DLLs in the Debug folder = didn't work either)
- I used the "add item" function so it can copy them itself
- I tried to run "Dependencies" over cvextern with a strange result (picture added)

[Dependencies Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh5kb.jpg)

it show's what I think might be a missing reference.. That DLL didn't exist but even after placing it where it belongs to it still seems to be missing.

Still I can't get rid of this error... Did I miss something? Hope you can help me out of this. If you need any further information about my problem pls let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to load cvextern in a c# project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028523/unable-to-load-cvextern-in-a-c-sharp-project)

Comment: that article is about an older version of Emgu. Unfortunately the solution there doesn't work in the current version

Comment: 1) The link (unable to load cvextern in a c# project) is a good "roadmap" for troubleshooting: cvextern load could fail because of an internal dependency, or a dependency on a dependency, etc.  2) Using "depends" was a Good Move!  3) Look here for several options on dealing with "Api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l1-1-0.dl": https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/12010