# Trying to get Emgu.CV running in dotnet core 3.1 on debian

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core, emgucv

So I am trying to get Emgu.CV running on debian, without any success yet.
I have the same error all the time, even when I fixed all the dependcies

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.
 ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'cvextern' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libcvextern: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.RedirectError(CvErrorCallback errorHandler, IntPtr userdata, IntPtr prevUserdata)
   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvCreateImageHeader(Size size, IplDepth depth, Int32 channels)
   at Emgu.CV.Image`2.AllocateData(Int32 rows, Int32 cols, Int32 numberOfChannels)
   at Emgu.CV.Image`2..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height)
```

I already upgraded to debian bullseye because of problems with GLIBC package. And I use the following commands to install dependencies:

```
# soft link
RUN ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.24.so /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so

# install System.Drawing native dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated \
        libc6-dev \
        libgdiplus \
        libx11-dev \
        libgeotiff-dev \
        libusb-dev \
        libxt-dev \
        libopengl-dev \
        libglx-dev \
     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Output of ldd command:

```
ldd libcvextern.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd3d2ca000)
        libgeotiff.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgeotiff.so.5 (0x00007f9a5ac44000)
        libusb-1.0.so.0 => not found
        libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f9a5ab01000)
        libXt.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 (0x00007f9a5aa97000)
        libOpenGL.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so.0 (0x00007f9a5aa6b000)
        libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f9a5aa37000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9a5aa13000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9a5aa0d000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f9a5a840000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9a5a6fc000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9a5a537000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9a611b0000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f9a5a51d000)
        libtiff.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007f9a5a495000)
        libproj.so.19 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.19 (0x00007f9a5a122000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f9a5a0f7000)
        libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f9a5a0ec000)
        libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f9a5a0ce000)
        libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f9a5a016000)
        libwebp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.6 (0x00007f9a59fab000)
        libzstd.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007f9a59ed0000)
        liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f9a59ea8000)
        libjbig.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0 (0x00007f9a59c9a000)
        libjpeg.so.62 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62 (0x00007f9a59c16000)
        libdeflate.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdeflate.so.0 (0x00007f9a59bfa000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f9a59bdb000)
        libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007f9a59a98000)
        libcurl-gnutls.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4 (0x00007f9a59a00000)
        libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f9a599fb000)
        libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f9a597f5000)
        libuuid.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f9a597ec000)
        libbsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f9a597d3000)
        libnghttp2.so.14 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnghttp2.so.14 (0x00007f9a597a6000)
        libidn2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007f9a59785000)
        librtmp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1 (0x00007f9a59766000)
        libssh2.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh2.so.1 (0x00007f9a59731000)
        libpsl.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpsl.so.5 (0x00007f9a5971b000)
        libnettle.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.8 (0x00007f9a596d3000)
        libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007f9a594d3000)
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f9a59480000)
        libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f9a5942a000)
        liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f9a59419000)
        libbrotlidec.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.so.1 (0x00007f9a59409000)
        libmd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmd.so.0 (0x00007f9a593fc000)
        libunistring.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007f9a5927a000)
        libhogweed.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.6 (0x00007f9a59231000)
        libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f9a591b0000)
        libgcrypt.so.20 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f9a5908e000)
        libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f9a58f5a000)
        libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f9a58f44000)
        libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f9a58e6a000)
        libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f9a58e3a000)
        libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f9a58e34000)
        libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f9a58e23000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f9a58e09000)
        libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007f9a58dec000)
        libbrotlicommon.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlicommon.so.1 (0x00007f9a58dc9000)
        libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f9a58da3000)
        libffi.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 (0x00007f9a58d95000)
        libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f9a58d8e000)
```

**Is there somebody who has any clue on what I am forgetting?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get the ldd-output right the Library libusb is missing:

```
libusb-1.0.so.0 => not found
```

Have you tried to install it to fix the issue?

Comment: So after installing libusb-1.0-0 this solved indeed the issue