# System.DllNotFoundException:Unable to load DLL 'cvextern': The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, deployment

I'm using Visual Studio 2022

Emgu.CV version  4.5.4.4788

Emgu.CV.Bitmap version  4.5.4.4788

Emgu.CV.runtine.windows version 4.5.4.4788

In debug and release mode I'm able to use everything in x64 and x86.

But when I publish it I'm getting an exception about the dlls

[exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKb3s.png)

I've read the documentation of [Emgu CV](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#The_type_initializer_for_.27Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.27_threw_an_exception) but couldn't find the solution.

They said I need some dlls that I can't find.

Comment: So, do you have mentioned cvextern.dll into your pulished package?

Comment: what do you mean by published package where can i find it?

Comment: You said `when I publish it`, so I assume that you have a bunch of files which is deployed somewhere and the app runned from there. So, is there `cvextern.dll` there? Also this may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028523/unable-to-load-cvextern-in-a-c-sharp-project

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and install the latest `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable` on your target machine.

There is new one for Visual Studio 2022.

Go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170